# How can I use VBA to fill in a JavaScript textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, vba, excel, jtextarea

I'm looking at the following JavaScript code:

```
<tr><td><textarea name="dump" rows="15" cols="80" maxlength="32768"></textarea></td></tr>
```

I need to fill this text area with a number of strings seperated by semicolons. I'm not sure if I've succeded, but also I'm not sure how I can update the website with the new HTML document.

Here's what I wrote:

```
Dim siteText As String

siteText = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML
siteText = InsertServer(siteText, "string") 'Where the character count is right before "</textarea>
```

Here's my function:

```
Function InsertServer(ByVal site As String, text As String) As String

InsertServer = Left(site, 9095) & text + ";" & Right(site, 9095 + Len(text))

End Function
```

**EDIT**

Since it seems to be a problem with the function call, I tried transforming it into a subroutine:

```
siteText = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML
InsertServer

Sub InsertServer()
siteText = Left(site, 9095) & "text" & ";" & Right(site, 9095 & Len(server))
End Sub
```

I also tried:

```
siteText = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML
insert = InsertServer(siteText, "text")

Sub InsertServer(site As String, text As String)
siteText = Left(site, 9095) & text & ";" & Right(site, 9095 & Len(server)) 
End Sub
```

Neither worked. I've only been work with VBA for a few weeks, so I'm really not sure what approach to take...

Comment: Is there an issue with your code when you try and execute it? If so, where abouts?

Comment: It loads and compiles just fine, but the text area isn't filled.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below. By the looks of it you're not concatenating strings correctly. You need to use `&` rather than `+`. Also, `Right(site, 9095 & Len(server))` should be a calculation rather `+` as below.

```
Function InsertServer(ByVal site As String, text As String) As String

InsertServer = Left(site, 9095) & text & ";" & Right(site, 9095 + Len(server))

End Function
```

**Edit**

Where you call the function, you've included an additional parameter which isn't needed according to the function:

```
siteText = InsertServer(siteText, "string", 9095) 'Where the character count is right before "</textarea>
```

Should be:

```
siteText = InsertServer(siteText, "string") 'Where the character count is right before "</textarea>
```

If there's no error being thrown when the code is executed, it indicates that the function is not being called at all.

Comment: I did indeed misplace that +. Unfortunately, I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: @user3785199 I have updated as there was another error with the calculation

Comment: Oh, yeah. I realized I didn't need that parameter, took it out, and still faced the same issue.

Comment: I tried removing `siteText = IE.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML` and it still loaded fine, so you must be right. There's some issue with the function call.